# Javascript resize and crop on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, resize, crop

I implement this resize and crop tool on my website : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

I changed some codes to have what I want, like a final crop picture with a size of 390px * 390px.

It works fine, but my site is responsive, and on a mobile device, the website width is 320px.

How can I changed my code to, on mobile version, have a smallest crop zone, but a final picture of 390px * 390px ?

Thanks.

Javascript code :

```
var resizeableImage = function(image_target) {
  // Some variable and settings
  var $container,
      orig_src = new Image(),
      image_target = $(image_target).get(0),
      event_state = {},
      constrain = false,
      min_width = 100, // Change as required
      min_height = 100,
      max_width = 900, // Change as required
      max_height = 900,
      resize_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  init = function(){

    // When resizing, we will always use this copy of the original as the base
    orig_src.src=image_target.src;

    // Wrap the image with the container and add resize handles
    $(image_target).wrap('<div class="resize-container"></div>')
    .before('<span class="resize-handle resize-handle-nw"></span>')
    .before('<span class="resize-handle resize-handle-ne"></span>')
    .after('<span class="resize-handle resize-handle-se"></span>')
    .after('<span class="resize-handle resize-handle-sw"></span>');

    // Assign the container to a variable
    $container =  $(image_target).parent('.resize-container');

    // Add events
    $container.on('mousedown touchstart', '.resize-handle', startResize);
    $container.on('mousedown touchstart', 'img', startMoving);
    $('.js-crop').on('click', crop);
  };

  startResize = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    saveEventState(e);
    $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', resizing);
    $(document).on('mouseup touchend', endResize);
  };

  endResize = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('mouseup touchend', endResize);
    $(document).off('mousemove touchmove', resizing);
  };

  saveEventState = function(e){
    // Save the initial event details and container state
    event_state.container_width = $container.width();
    event_state.container_height = $container.height();
    event_state.container_left = $container.offset().left; 
    event_state.container_top = $container.offset().top;
    event_state.mouse_x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 
    event_state.mouse_y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();

    // This is a fix for mobile safari
    // For some reason it does not allow a direct copy of the touches property
    if(typeof e.originalEvent.touches !== 'undefined'){
        event_state.touches = [];
        $.each(e.originalEvent.touches, function(i, ob){
          event_state.touches[i] = {};
          event_state.touches[i].clientX = 0+ob.clientX;
          event_state.touches[i].clientY = 0+ob.clientY;
        });
    }
    event_state.evnt = e;
  };

  resizing = function(e){
    var mouse={},width,height,left,top,offset=$container.offset();
    mouse.x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 
    mouse.y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();

    // Position image differently depending on the corner dragged and constraints
    if( $(event_state.evnt.target).hasClass('resize-handle-se') ){
      width = mouse.x - event_state.container_left;
      height = mouse.y  - event_state.container_top;
      left = event_state.container_left;
      top = event_state.container_top;
    } else if($(event_state.evnt.target).hasClass('resize-handle-sw') ){
      width = event_state.container_width - (mouse.x - event_state.container_left);
      height = mouse.y  - event_state.container_top;
      left = mouse.x;
      top = event_state.container_top;
    } else if($(event_state.evnt.target).hasClass('resize-handle-nw') ){
      width = event_state.container_width - (mouse.x - event_state.container_left);
      height = event_state.container_height - (mouse.y - event_state.container_top);
      left = mouse.x;
      top = mouse.y;
      if(constrain || e.shiftKey){
        top = mouse.y - ((width / orig_src.width * orig_src.height) - height);
      }
    } else if($(event_state.evnt.target).hasClass('resize-handle-ne') ){
      width = mouse.x - event_state.container_left;
      height = event_state.container_height - (mouse.y - event_state.container_top);
      left = event_state.container_left;
      top = mouse.y;
      if(constrain || e.shiftKey){
        top = mouse.y - ((width / orig_src.width * orig_src.height) - height);
      }
    }

    // Optionally maintain aspect ratio
    if(constrain || e.shiftKey){
      height = width / orig_src.width * orig_src.height;
    }

    /*if(width > min_width && height > min_height && width < max_width && height < max_height){
      // To improve performance you might limit how often resizeImage() is called
      resizeImage(width, height);  
      // Without this Firefox will not re-calculate the the image dimensions until drag end
      $container.offset({'left': left, 'top': top});
    }*/

    if(width > min_width && height > min_height /*&& width < max_width && height < max_height*/){
        // To improve performance you might limit how often resizeImage() is called
        resizeImage(width, height);
        // Without this Firefox will not re-calculate the the image dimensions until drag end
        $container.offset({'left': left, 'top': top});
    }

  }

  resizeImage = function(width, height){
    resize_canvas.width = width;
    resize_canvas.height = height;
    resize_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(orig_src, 0, 0, width, height);   
    $(image_target).attr('src', resize_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));  
  };

  startMoving = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    saveEventState(e);
    $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', moving);
    $(document).on('mouseup touchend', endMoving);
  };

  endMoving = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('mouseup touchend', endMoving);
    $(document).off('mousemove touchmove', moving);
  };

  moving = function(e){
    var  mouse={}, touches;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    touches = e.originalEvent.touches;

    mouse.x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft(); 
    mouse.y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();
    $container.offset({
      'left': mouse.x - ( event_state.mouse_x - event_state.container_left ),
      'top': mouse.y - ( event_state.mouse_y - event_state.container_top ) 
    });
    // Watch for pinch zoom gesture while moving
    if(event_state.touches && event_state.touches.length > 1 && touches.length > 1){
      var width = event_state.container_width, height = event_state.container_height;
      var a = event_state.touches[0].clientX - event_state.touches[1].clientX;
      a = a * a; 
      var b = event_state.touches[0].clientY - event_state.touches[1].clientY;
      b = b * b; 
      var dist1 = Math.sqrt( a + b );

      a = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX - touches[1].clientX;
      a = a * a; 
      b = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY - touches[1].clientY;
      b = b * b; 
      var dist2 = Math.sqrt( a + b );

      var ratio = dist2 /dist1;

      width = width * ratio;
      height = height * ratio;
      // To improve performance you might limit how often resizeImage() is called
      resizeImage(width, height);
    }
  };

  crop = function(){
    //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
    var crop_canvas,
    left = $('.overlay').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
    top =  $('.overlay').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
    width = $('.overlay').width(),
    height = $('.overlay').height();

    crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    crop_canvas.width = width;
    crop_canvas.height = height;

    crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
    //window.open(crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    var canvasData = crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'upload_picture.php',false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    ajax.send(canvasData)
  }

  init();
};
```

HTML code :

```
<div id="crop_canvas">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <img class="resize-image" src="mypicture.jpg" />
</div>
<button class="btn-crop js-crop">Découper</button>
```

CSS code :

```
.resize-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: move;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.resize-container img {
    display: block
}

.resize-container:hover img,
.resize-container:active img {
    outline: 2px dashed rgba(222,60,80,.9);
}

.resize-handle-ne,
.resize-handle-ne,
.resize-handle-se,
.resize-handle-nw,
.resize-handle-sw {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: rgba(222,60,80,.9);
    z-index: 999;
}

.resize-handle-nw {
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: nw-resize;
}

.resize-handle-sw {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: sw-resize;
}

.resize-handle-ne {
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: ne-resize;
}

.resize-handle-se {
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: se-resize;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left:40%;
    top:31%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    z-index: 999;
    width:390px;
    height:390px;
    border: solid 2px #f8b028;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.overlay:after,
.overlay:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 394px;
    height: 40px;
    border-left: dashed 2px #f8b028;
    border-right: dashed 2px #f8b028;
}

.overlay:before {
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.overlay:after {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.overlay-inner:after,
.overlay-inner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 394px;
    border-top: dashed 2px #f8b028;
    border-bottom: dashed 2px #f8b028;
}

.overlay-inner:before {
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.overlay-inner:after {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -40px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.btn-crop {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    right:20px;
    bottom:13px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color:#f8b028;
    border: none;
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#crop_modal .modal-dialog{width:980px;}

#crop_modal .modal-content{
    background:#0082c6;
    border-radius:0;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

#crop_modal .modal-content p{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
}

#crop_canvas{
    background:#fff;
    border:3px solid #f8b028;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

You can find a demo here : http://darkcid.olympe.in/

Comment: 390px * 390px this size. Have you done this by css or js??

Comment: I don't fully understand the tool, but the size of the crop zone is defined by css. I don't have to change anythinig in the javascript code to change the size of the final picture.

Comment: if you can provide me some demo then I can tell you clearly what to do. or else if you are using css. you can use @media queries eg. @media(max-width: 767px){ //code }

Comment: OK, I can't give you the actuel url, but I will make a demo a soon as possible ;)

Comment: I create a demo : http://darkcid.olympe.in/
It's in french but I think it will not be a problem ;)